# info about a memory leak using ARC in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

Good Evening,
I have a small doubt about ARC.
If I have this following code:

```
- (void)parseStream:(NSDictionary *)response
{

    feedItems = [AFeedlyClientStream new];

    [feedItems setID:response[kFeedlyIDKey]];
    [feedItems setTitle:response[kFeedlyTitleKey]];
    [feedItems setDirection:response[kFeedlyDirectionKey]];
    [feedItems setContinuation:response[kFeedlyContinuationKey]];
    [feedItems setUpdated:[response[kFeedlyUpdatedKey] longLongValue]];

    NSArray *items = response[kFeedlyItemsKey];
    [feedItems setItems:[self parseEntries:items]];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"DidLoadFeedItems"
     object:self];
}
```

Where feedItems is an object of the class `AFeedlyClientStream`.
My question is:
If I call a lot of time that method... does the `feedItems = [AFeedlyClientStream new];` release memory?
Or I must do something else? It is a heavy object.

/* UPDATE */
Declaration of feedItems

```
AFeedlyClientStream *feedItems;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AFeedlyClientStream *feedItems;
```

Comment: `feedItems` will receive a `release` message when it goes out of scope. That may or may not mean that it's immediately deleted.

Comment: Where is `feedItems` declared?

Comment: Info about declaration added!

Comment: Hm, so it's an instance variable? In that case, something different will happen. Ivars are `strong` by default -- i. e. the release will happen upon reassignment (and upon destruction of the containing object).

Comment: (Also note that as your code currently standing, `feedItems` will **not** be the backing ivar for the `self.feedItems` property because of auto property synthesis "helpfully" adding leading underscores.)

Comment: mmm thanks @TheParamagneticCroissant, I can't understand your last comment. What's is the way I must manage the feedItems?

I must use the _ (underscore) every time I use it?

Comment: You can delete this line: `AFeedlyClientStream *feedItems;`. The auto property synthesis will automatically create a backing ivar for your property called `_feedItems`

Comment: Thanks, can you explain me why? :)

Comment: @UsiUsi Because the engineers over at Apple decided that this is how it should work.

Comment: ahahaha sure, but maybe there is a technical explanation...

Comment: You can read more about auto property synthesis here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html The whole blog post may be a bit overkill but reading the first few paragraphs should already give you a better understanding of the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) will automatically manage memory so you don't need to worry about memory management. You only need to know some basic stuff like the difference between weak and strong references and you have to make sure you don't create strong reference cycles. But besides these things, you don't need to send retain or release messages to objects. ARC will automatically insert these when a strong reference goes out of scope for example.
So to answer your question: 
The snippet you posted is perfectly fine and ARC will automatically do the right thing to manage the reference count, and thus memory for you. As stated in the comments, the object `feedItems` references will automatically receive a release message if you assign a pointer to another object to `feedItems`. This means the object will also be deallocated if `feedItems` was the only variable holding a strong reference to it.